# How to write a TRIGGER that handles MULTIPLE ROWS and GROUP BY user id

Tags: group-by, triggers, mysql-error-1242

I'm trying to write a trigger that handles multiple rows inserts in the sourcetable and also group the rows by user id (there are several user id under a specific column in the sourcetable called user_id).

Here is my query. I cannot make it work. I'm not sure where the error is.

```
delimiter//      
CREATE TRIGGER refresh_5 AFTER INSERT  
ON sourcetable  
FOR EACH ROW  
UPDATE Revenue  
SET  
user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM sourcetable),  
YEAR1 = (SELECT SUM(priceyear1*quantityyear1) FROM sourcetable),  
YEAR2 = (SELECT SUM(priceyear2*quantityyear2) FROM sourcetable),  
YEAR3 = (SELECT SUM(priceyear3*quantityyear3) FROM sourcetable),  
YEAR4 = (SELECT SUM(priceyear4*quantityyear4) FROM sourcetable),  
YEAR1 = (SELECT SUM(priceyear5*quantityyear5) FROM sourcetable)  
GROUP BY user_id;//  
delimiter;
```